# getDefaultProps method inside of class, versus class.DefaultProps

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component called SkiDaysCount, where I output some data and make a simple calculation.

What is the difference between declaring the default props with the getDefaultProps method like such

```js
getDefaultProps() {
  return {
    total: 50,
    powder: 50,
    backcountry: 15,
    goal: 75
  };
}
```

and assigning them in your App.js/Index.js like this:

```js
SkiDaysCount.defaultProps = {
  total: 50,
  powder: 10,
  BackCountry: 15,
  goal: 75
};
```

and then just  assigning the values inside the place, where you place your component

```js
<SkiDaysCount
  total={70}
  powder={20}
  backcountry={10}
  goal={75}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `getDefaultProps` method used to be the way to [set default props with `createReactClass`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props). This way of setting default props doesn't work with ES6 classes, so you need to use `defaultProps` for that.

**Example**

```js
class SkiDaysCount1 extends React.Component {
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      total: 50,
      powder: 50,
      backcountry: 15,
      goal: 75
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props)}</div>;
  }
}

class SkiDaysCount2 extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    total: 50,
    powder: 50,
    backcountry: 15,
    goal: 75
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props)}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <SkiDaysCount1 />
    <SkiDaysCount2 />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```